# laravel-Upload laravel project to shared hosting issue

Tags: laravel

I had upload my laravel project to host and change .env file but 
get this error: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
and no other error

Comment: Check the error logs on your host

Comment: there isn't error in error log

Comment: Check the laravel.log file also.

Comment: In my opinion, don't use Laravel on shared hosting or use an installer to install Laravel on the server. Like GoDaddy has Laravel 5.1 installer.

Comment: go to your `.env` file and then set `APP_DEBUG=true`

Answer (score 0):

add this in your route and try calling /clear-cache url

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() { $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');  });
```